# Concerning how a probability question is worded

Tags: probability

In the below question, we are asked to "calculate the probability that there will be at least four months in which no accidents occur before the fourth month in which at least one accident occurs."

I am having a misunderstanding because I don't see how we can have at least four months of no accidents before the fourth month arrives. Unless this problem means that there are four months without accidents, followed by four months of accidents.

[image]

Comment: Four months of no accidents can be there before the fourth month **in wich accidents occur** arrives. E.g. let $ANNNANANA$ chronologically stand for a sequence of $9$ months. $N$ denotes a month in wich no accidents occur and $A$ a month in which accidents occurs. Then the $9$-th month is the fourth month *with accidents*. It is preceded by five months *without accidents*.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is saying that each month can be classified as having an accident occurring (A) or not having an accident occurring (B).  Thus as the months go by you get a sequence of As and Bs (e.g. AABBBABAAB...)  The question is what is the probability of a total of $4$ Bs before there has been a total fo $4$ As. (I would say that neither the As nor the Bs need to be consecutive.)